# How to use ng-repeat to create a table with some columns as dropdown

Tags: angularjs

I have the Following JSON

```
[{
  "CompID": "0001388D",
  "Domains": [{
    "Banking": 1,
    "Finance": "Working",
    "ECommerce": "Working"
  }],
  "CompName": "INFY",
  "CompLoc": "IN"
}, {
  "CompID": "0001388D2",
  "Domains": [{
    "Banking": 1,
    "Finance": "Working",
    "ECommerce": "Working"
  }],
  "CompName": "TCS",
  "CompLoc": "IN"
}]
```

Using Angular JS i am representing the above data in a tabular format as shown below

```
<table border="1">
      <tr>
         <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]" ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)==-1">{{ key }}</th>
      </tr>
      <tr ng-repeat="row in collectioninfo">
         <td ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in row" >
            {{ val2 }}
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
```

This Works , but i want to represent **Domains** as a **Drop Down** value .

I have tried as using ng-if where `allDropDownsHere` scope value contains all values which needs to be presented in drop down

```
  <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]" ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)==-1">{{ key }}</th>
```

This is my fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9fR23/488/

Could you please tell me how to achive the desired result ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand you correctly following will help you.

Following is a general solution based on your question. which assumes the following.

1. The key of the drop down columns must be in the array  `$scope.allDropDownsHere`
2. The dropdown colums is an array and values in its zeroth position is repeated as a dropdown.

```js
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.allDropDownsHere = ['Domains']


  $scope.collectioninfo = [{
      "CompID": "0001388D",
      "Domains": [{
        "Banking": 1,
        "Finance": "Working",
        "ECommerce": "Working"
      }],
      "CompName": "INFY",
      "CompLoc": "IN"
    },
    {
      "CompID": "0001388D2",
      "Domains": [{
        "Banking": 1,
        "Finance": "Working",
        "ECommerce": "Working"
      }],
      "CompName": "TCS",
      "CompLoc": "IN"
    },
    {
      "CompID": "0001388D23",
      "Domains": [{
        "Banking": 1,
        "Finance": "Working",
        "ECommerce": "Working"
      }],
      "CompName": "WIPRO",
      "CompLoc": "IN"

    }
  ]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myapp" ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
  <table border="1">
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="(key, val) in collectioninfo[0]">
        <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)>=0">
          <select>
            <option>{{key}}</option>
            <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val[0]" value="{{v}}">{{k}}</option>
          </select>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key)<0">
          {{ key }}
        </span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in collectioninfo">
      <td ng-repeat="(key2, val2) in row">
        <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)>=0">
          <select>
            <option ng-repeat="(k, v) in val2[0]" value="{{v}}">{{k}}</option>
          </select>
        </span>
        <span ng-if="allDropDownsHere.indexOf(key2)<0">
          {{ val2 }}
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: First of All thanks a lot for the help , Sorry for the Confusion , Under the Domains Header i wanted to have drop down with three values Banking , Finance , ECommerce

Comment: The Header part is needed that change you just made

Comment: to be more clearer , The header and column should be same

Comment: you mean it should be same as that in your question. Uh.?

Comment: no , let me make you clear , right now there are 4 headers , 
CompID CompLoc CompName Domains , The Domains header should be of dropdown value

Comment: @ kiran what should be in the dropdown in header .? meaning in domain.?

Comment: i have added a picture for you , please see and on click of the dropdown it should display Banking , Finance , ECommerce

Comment: On click of the Domains , it should display Banking ,Finance ,ECommerce

Comment: same as it is happening as for the column

Comment: thanks once again , u saved me atleast 3-4 days of tension work . God bless